# Redirect to another route when accessing a route in react

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a use case where i want to redirect from '/' route to /login whenever someone hits the '/' route. For more clarity i have an app that points to 'app.web.com/login' as the login page. When someone tries to access 'app.web.com' it should redirect to 'app.web.com/login'. I am using react router version 6 and this is what i have tried.

```
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/'>
          <Navigate to="/auth/login" />
        </Route>
        <Route path='auth' element={<AuthView />}>
          <Route path='login' element={<LoginView />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundView />} />
      </Routes>
```

But it does not have the desired effect. I am pretty much just picking react up so i am sure there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: You should have a look [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) and [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#adding-a-no-match-route)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is make a small component which is rendered on the '/' route which redirects you to the login page.

You could use the useHistory hook for that.

Below is an example of how a component like that looks like.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export const RedirectToLogin: React.FC = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        history.push('/auth/login');
    });

    return null;
};
```

Your router component would look like:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<RedirectToLogin />} />
    <Route path='auth' element={<AuthView />}>
      <Route path='login' element={<LoginView />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' element={<NotFoundView />} />
  </Routes
```

Comment: I actually thought of this but i was hoping for a simpler way in which i wouldn't have to create a new component. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it. Have the "/" route point to the same element as the "/login" path.

```
    <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Routes>
    <Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly then you want to redirect the user to `login` page if the user is not `logged in`.

So what you can do is, Instead of trying to do it using `route`, you can do it from the component which gets rendered when the user goes to `/`.

You can check in the `useEffect hook` that if the user exists then go to `/` else go to `/login`.

Use the example from below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!user) {
    navigate('/')
  }
}, [user])
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not an authentication process. The project structure includes '/dashboard' and also a '/login' route. I am just trying to do a simple redirect to login route if the '/' route is being accessed. I do not have a landing page so i want all requests to '/' to just redirect to the login page

Comment: Thank you but this is not an authentication process. The project structure includes '/dashboard' and also a '/login' route. I am just trying to do a simple redirect to login route if the '/' route is being accessed. I do not have a landing page so i want all requests to '/' to just redirect to the login page

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple to just use **Navigate** from react-router-dom. You go make a new component, I named it **home** and just have it have the Navigate function which takes in an object with the **to** key, that you then set to the desired redirect location.

```js
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

function Home() {
  
  Navigate({ to: '/login' })

}

export default Home
```